# Is it correct / desirable to use HTTP 405 when a resource is (perhaps temporarily) not editable?

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

I'm wondering about the correct status code to return in a situation where a resource is modifiable through PUT requests while it is in 'editable' state but not otherwise. In particular, where a client attempts to PUT the resource whilst it's not editable.

If the client was able to take some steps to make the resource editable then `409 Conflict` might be appropriate, but that doesn't apply in my situation; the editable status of the resource is under the server's control.

`405 Method not allowable` seems the closest semantic fit, but it's not the normal use.

What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem allowing the available methods to change over time.  Consider another example where something cannot be deleted once it has reached a particular state.

Answer (score 0):

I think `405` is ok, but if you want to be more specific, you may consider using `423 Locked` (from WebDAV https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.3) if it is applicable to your situation (i.e. that the file is not editable due to a lock-like restriction instead of ACL for instance)